# Can I get snow and light at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On our 1.0 minecraft server, the spawn is in the center of a snow biome.

We started to create a nice little village near the spawn, building wooden houses and buildings to match with the snow theme.

However, we'd like to make the village safer, and thus need to put some more lighting on the surroundings.

Currently, if we put torches on the ground or near snow, the snow will melt and leave an empty ground. As we do like the snow theme for our village, how can we arrange the lighting to preserve the snow on a maximum of blocks and prevent mob spawning in the area ?

Is possible, we would like to avoid having glass on the ground, which is not really realistic.

Comment: I don't think crafted snow blocks can melt, so you could dig out the dirt and replace it with snow blocks. They're different from the sides, and are slightly lower than "block with snow on top", though... might be a solution for within the radius that the torches melt, though. Can mobs even spawn on snow?

Comment: Yes mobs can spawn on snow. I remember playing back when there was a 1/5 chance your world would be snowy (pre-biomes) and there were *definitely* plenty of mobs around!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your best bet is to place **torches** or **glowstone** (or even fire or lava) a sufficient distance in the air (using lampposts) that the light level at the ground isn't sufficient to melt the snow, but is sufficient to stop mobs spawning. [The answers in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33377/is-there-an-easy-way-to-calculate-a-blocks-light-level) should help you with this calculation.

Comment: Lampposts are a good solution for roads and such, as it fits correctly with the village, but having lampposts in every empty area seems a bit strange. I guess there is no real alternative to light blank spaces :-(

Comment: Probably not. :( Or just use floating glowstone blocks. ;)

Comment: I use the floating glowstone blocks in my servers.  BUt that's because i'm strange ;P  (I have an entire village made from glowstones :P)

Answer (score 1):

If using the standard Minecraft server isn't a requirement, I know there are a ton of Bukkit plugins that let you control the melt of snow and ice (and presumably Canary has similar, although I don't use it.)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you just use glowstone, add 2 layers of glass and 1 layer of leaves at the top to stop the heat, but not the light and you cover it with snow, no melting at all, just since the glowstone is kinda in the ground, it lights up a bit less, but it is invisible, so you can use it as much as you want

Comment: There is no such thing as "stopping the heat". Snow melts at block light level 12 and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using snow blocks, they don't melt.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wool to fill the spots that the torches melt. Depending on your texture pack, you can make it so you can't tell wool from snow using this method.

Answer (score 0):

you could use redstone lamps in the ground with levers underneath them, so that they are constantly on. I think that lamps don't melt snow, but I am not totally sure.